# Is there a way to get a single keystroke in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I need a way to check the keyboard, see if any single key has been pressed and if so get the key and if not, leave and go about my business.  I only need to check about a half dozen keys.  And I will return to check often (i.e., this check is in a part of the program that repeats endlessly [as long as the program is running.]  Alternatively, I guess I could also implement it as an interrupt, i.e., do the rest of the loop and go get the key when pressed.

Because get and getc both wait for a return, they won't work for me.  I found examples in java and on windows but I'm on a Mac.

Comment: Just to clarify, we're talking about a shell script, not a web/cgi one, right?

Comment: Not sure what that means, but if shell script means on a computer and web/cgi means getting something across the internet, then yes to shell script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To read a character immediately without giving the tty device a chance to edit the characters and wait for a return, you would need something like this:

```
system 'stty cbreak'
$stdout.syswrite 'How now: '
q = $stdin.sysread 1
puts
puts "You typed #{q} it seems."
system 'stty cooked'
```

To add a check for a character being available, extend it to do a non-blocking read...

```
def read1maybe
  return $stdin.read_nonblock 1
rescue Errno::EAGAIN
  return ''
end

system 'stty cbreak'
while true
  q = read1maybe
  break if q.length > 0
  puts 'you did not change anything'
  sleep 1
end
puts
puts "You typed #{q} it seems."
system 'stty cooked'
```

For something more elaborate, see [the standard library curses package.](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/curses/rdoc/Curses.html) You may also find [io/console](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html) useful.

Comment: That works great.  Needles to say, I would have never discovered this from reading the Ruby documentation. I'm glad I asked. Thanks so much.

Comment: Sorry to say, it does not do what I need after all.  Although it does not require a return, this routine still waits around for a key-press. Previously I had been able to check a buffer (on the Apple][) which held the value of the last key pressed.  If it was nil, I went about my business, otherwise I retrieved the value and used it in my program accordingly. Is there a way this can do the line q = $stdin.sysread 1 and not pause waiting to read q?

Comment: Urk, I should read the questions more carefully. Update added!

Comment: Thanks a lot DR, this seems to work.  I'll be putting it in my program and let you know.